# How can I see the TLS version of an incoming API request - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, azure, .net-4.5, tls1.2, webapi

I have a web app hosted on Microsoft Azure that includes a Web API. I am targeting .NET Framework 4.5.

I am working through all the required steps in order to make TLS 1.2 the minimum version required for incoming requests.

Before I officially switch to TLS 1.2 minimum for incoming requests, I would like to know if anyone is currently using older TLS versions, since we have third parties using our API.

Is there a way to detect the TLS version that was negotiated in a specific API request?

For example, I have this API call below. What code can I write using .NET Framework 4.5 that will get the TLS version that was negotiated?

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Roles = "User")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetFirstName()
        {
            // I would like to add code here to get TLS version negotiated so I can log it

            var email = User.Identity.GetUserName();
            ApplicationUser userFound = GetUserByEmail(email);
            if (userFound == null)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Error: No such user.");
            }
            var firstName = new { FirstName = userFound.FirstName };

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, firstName);
        }
```

I know I eventually need to upgrade .NET Framework altogether, but I need a quick solution on 4.5 before I can tackle that.

Comment: The quick solution is to upgrade to a *supported* version, ie 4.6.2 and later. 4.5 never supported TLS 1.2 to begin with without hacks, so you *can't* see what's going on. Your own application negotiates the use of TLS 1.1 at best. The only clients that would use TLS 1.1 are unpatched, unsupported Windows versions. All others support it already. Given that major browsers and services like Chrome and GMail require TLS 1.2 for several years now, all clients upgraded years ago

Comment: Chrome for example [deprecated TLS 1.1 back in 2020](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-84-deps-rems/#remove-tls-10-and-tls-11)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am setting ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = TLS 1.2 in Application_Start() in Global.asax.cs so I am able to make requests with TLS 1.2. I have 3rd parties using legacy systems to connect to our API, so I need to be able to identify them and alert them of the upcoming change to TLS 1.2 being required for incoming requests. So I was hoping there was a way to at least identify the TLS version of incoming requests using .NET Framework 4.5 since at the moment I am supporting any TLS version for incoming requests

Comment: If you use `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` then you  already demand TLS 1.2, preventing connections using either TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.3. That means all clients already use TLS 1.2

Comment: In any case, the real solution is to *upgrade* to 4.6.2 and *remove* all hard-coded TLS versions. This will allow .NET to use the best option offered by the OS. In all supported Windows versions that's TLS 1.2, while in Windows 11 and Windows Server 2022 you also get TLS 1.3

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, Panagiotis Kanavos point is valid. Upgrading to a supported version of .NET Framework, such as 4.6.2 or later may help more.

As you can check here in MS [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#for-net-framework-35---452-and-not-wcf) saying that if you are using 4.5v you need to upgrade for the latest version.
[image]

I have tried for the newer version of .NET Framework 4.6.1. I can access the TLS version information directly from the `SslStream` class.

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace YourNamespace.Controllers
{
    public class YourController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
        {
            await LogNegotiatedTLSVersion(Request);

            // Your existing code here

            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new ObjectContent<string>("Hello, World!", new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()),
            };
        }

        private async Task LogNegotiatedTLSVersion(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            object property;
            if (request.Properties.TryGetValue("MS_HttpContext", out property))
            {
                var context = (System.Web.HttpContextWrapper)property;
                var stream = context.Response.Filter as System.Web.HttpBufferedOutputStream;

                if (stream != null)
                {
                    var sslStreamField = stream.GetType().GetField("_sslStream", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                    var sslStream = sslStreamField?.GetValue(stream) as System.Net.Security.SslStream;

                    if (sslStream != null)
                    {
                        // Log the negotiated TLS version
                        Console.WriteLine($"Negotiated TLS version: {sslStream.SslProtocol}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- The `SslStream.SslProtocol` property is used to get the negotiated TLS version. The `AuthenticateAsServer` method is called to authenticate the server side of the connection.

Comment: I tried your solution but I am stuck because my Request object is an HttpRequestMessage, not an HttpRequest. Do you know of a way to utilize HttpRequestMessage to get the same result?

Comment: @IMSsam You can still extract TLS information, but you'll need to use the HttpRequestMessage.Properties dictionary to access the underlying SslStream and retrieve the TLS version. please check my updated answer.

Comment: In your original ans, you used request.HttpContext.Connection.Stream, i guess thats not available in net core now